# Deleting commits with git rebase

Tags: git

I've got a git branch (let's say "dev") with this configuration

`...- before - A - B - HEAD`

B is a revert commit from A. That means, A and B are useless and only the head is important.

I would like to remove A and B and set the HEAD to get `before - HEAD`

But I can't find how to do this with a rebase, because I don't want to use the commits at all.

NB: One way would be going back to 'before'and apply HEAD into a new branch I guess, but this is not what i'm looking for here. I don't want to create an other branch.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interactive rebase would be a good option here (`git rebase -i before` and deleting the `A` and `B` lines), but if you are looking to avoid that, here is a slightly more simple approach:

First, keep track of the SHA of your head commit. Let's call that `123`.

```
git reset --hard before # move your HEAD pointer back to the "before" commit
git cherry-pick 123     # copy back over your original HEAD commit
```

Since `A` and `B` cancel themselves out there should be no conflict during this operation.

Then, you'll need to force-push if you had already pushed `A` or `B`: `git push -f origin master`. If you have teammates on your project you should let them know before a force-push.

Comment: The solution that @axiac provided, using `--onto`, while (arguably) more advanced than my approach, is probably more slick.

Comment: I don't want to avoid using git rebase it's just I think I can't do this with an interractive rebase, the commits will be "merge" into one, but even if we can't see the commit message, they will still be there). I really want to "destroy them" or at least hide them.

Your solution with the shawan will create a new branch no ? I don't think the link between begore and A can be cut just with the cherry pick ? Not sure thought.

Comment: My approach doesn't create a new branch. During the interactive rebase step, when you have the chance to edit the commits in the list, just delete the lines for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't see into the documentation removing lines were allowed. So I guess this is what I was looking for.

Comment: It worked fine, but I forgot I had already pushed A on remote :(
There won't be any issue to do git rebase -i origin/dev HEAD right ? And then deleting the commit A on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

Your Git graph is not very clear. In a Git repo, `HEAD` is a reference that points to the current branch (that, in turn, is a reference that points to a commit).

Assuming the structure of your repo is like this (the letters denote commits)

```
... X - Y - A - B - Z    (<--dev)
```

... the current branch points to `Z` and you want to get rid of commits `A` and `B` (and make `Z` a child of `Y`), the Git command you are looking for is:

```
git rebase --onto Y B
```

This command moves all commits that are reachable from the current branch (`dev`, pointing to `Z`) but are not reachable from `B` on top of commit `Y`.

Read more about [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

---

No matter how do you accomplish your goal, if you have already pushed the commit `A` to the remote repository, the operation will make your history line of the current branch different than the one already published.

You need to use `git push --force` to make your version the official version but this will confuse your co-workers and Git cannot help you with it. The communication is the key to solve such a situation.

Comment: I prefer working with interractive rebase, but I will look at your solution too after. At the end : Is there any differences between your way and removing the lines in the interractive.

Comment: [`git rebase -i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--i) can be used for more advanced processing of the history line (you can squash, remove, reorder and edit the commits). There is no difference in the outcome between the command line I suggested and `git rebase -i Y` when you remove the commits `A` and `B` from the rebase plan (the list of actions and commit hashes that Git opens in the editor on `git rebase -i`). In the end, for such a simple action it is just a matter of preference. I prefer the command line because I get the job done faster this way.